# how to notify all the threads if there is unknown number of threads in java

Tags: java

This is a part of my java code. In this code there are labels which are counting numbers from 0 up to so on.

I want to stop labels to count when I click the button 1st time, and I want to restart the labels to count again when I click the button 2nd time. The problem is that the labels are not restarting their counting when I am clicking the button 2nd time. So please tell me how should I notify all the labels to restart their counting?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
public class Main implements ActionListener {
    JButton button = new JButton("Click");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    boolean wait=false;

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        new Producer().execute();
    }

    public class Producer extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        public Void doInBackground() {
            for(int infinite=0; infinite!=-1; infinite++) {
                new Counter().execute();
                try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}     
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Counter extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        public Counter() {
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            frame.add(label);
        }

        public Void doInBackground() {
            synchronized (this) {
                for(int i=0; i!=-1; i++) {
                    if(wait==true)
                        try {this.wait();} catch(Exception exp) {exp.printStackTrace();}
                    label.setText(""+i);
                    try {Thread.sleep(200);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}      
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clicked) {
        if(wait==false)
            wait=true;
        else if(wait==true) {
            synchronized (this) {
                this.notifyAll();
            }
            wait=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you are accessing and mutating Swing components from off of the EDT. This is in direct contravention of Swing's threading policy and I would strongly suggest you read a tutorial on Swing programming before writing any more code.

Comment: Why not set up a separate Count object one a Single thread that will increment all the counters you want ... call the COunt to register a new one (and return an id), then call to get the value.  NO sense starting all those threads .. threads are expensive!

Comment: "Stop the labels to count" does not parse.  How do you "stop" a label, and are the labels doing the counting or are you?  And, of course, there's no way to arbitrarily stop other threads.  What you can do is somehow rendezvous with the other threads and exchange information.

Comment: You've asked three questions about the same program? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694702/threads-are-not-being-notified-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695871/only-one-thread-is-being-notifid-instead-of-two

Answer (score 2):

The `this` in  `this.notifyAll()` is not the same object as the `this` in `this.wait()`.