# threads are not being notified in java

Tags: java

In this code two threads are running, I am putting both the threads on wait when button is clicked 1st time, when the button is clicked 2nd time I am notifying both the threads but they are not being notified please help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;



public class Main implements ActionListener {


    JButton button = new JButton("Click");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    boolean wait=false;
    Counter c[] = new Counter[2];

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        c[0]=new Counter();
        c[0].execute();
        c[1]=new Counter();
        c[1].execute();
    }

    public class Counter extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        public Counter() {
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            frame.add(label);
        }

        public Void doInBackground() {
            synchronized (this) {
                for(int i=0; i!=-1; i++) {
                    if(wait==true)
                        try {this.wait();} catch(Exception exp) {exp.printStackTrace();}
                    label.setText(""+i);
                    try {Thread.sleep(200);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}      
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clicked) {
        if(wait==false)
            wait=true;
        else if(wait==true) {
            synchronized (c) {
                c.notifyAll();
            }
            wait=false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You need to wait on the same object that is notified.**

The `notifyAll()` call is done on `c`. When you call `this.wait()`, `this` refers to the two counters `c[0]` and `c[1]`. That's a problem because `c[0]` and `c[1]` are not the same object as the array `c`.

Replace `this` with `c`.

```
public Void doInBackground() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i != -1; i++) {
            synchronized (c) {
                // Check the wait condition in a loop to guard against spurious
                // wakeups.
                while (wait == true) {
                    c.wait();
                }
            }

            label.setText("" + i);
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        // Exit the loop if the thread is interrupted.
    }

    return null;
}
```

I made some other improvements as well:

1. The `wait()` function can encounter spurious wakeups. It's normally supposed to return only when some other thread has called `notify()`, but it's possible for `wait()` to return for no particular reason sometimes. That's a spurious wakeup. To guard against spurious wakeups, you should always call `wait()` in a loop and check your wait condition.
2. I reduced the scope of the `synchronized` block as much as possible. When you're in there you will cause other threads to block, so you need to get in and get out as quick as you can. Do not do any heavy lifting in there. Do not call GUI code while holding a lock. **Do not sleep inside a synchronized block.**